# Reminders going off at the wrong time

Tags: macos, reminders

I have a daily reminder that is set to trigger at 3am. However, they seem to be triggering around 10pm on both my Macbook, my iPhone, and my iPad. Why? How can I stop this?

Comment: Does this work the same (5 hours wrong) with all reminders, or just this one?  It sounds like a timezone issue, but rather than have an answer, I just have questions that revolve around you testing for setting a reminder, calendar event, and alarm clock alert for the same time, 9say 10 minutes from now) and see what happens.

Comment: I've actually been having several problems resembling this, but much worse: They've gone off _days_ in advance. Reminders set to go off on Sunday are going off on Wednesday... It's a rare occurrence, but wow, just odd.

Comment: I have new info: it happens to the recurring reminders that you didn't mark as done but the next recurring reminder gets replicated behind the scenes. Example: I have a daily reminder that I haven't marked as done for a few days.